# $X_n$ s.t $E[\sup _n |X _{n+1}-X_n|]< \infty$ and $X_0 =0$. Prove that a.s $\limsup X _n=-\liminf X _n =\infty$ or $\lim X _n$ exsits and finite

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, martingales

> $X_n$ s.t $E[\sup _n |X _{n+1}-X_n|]< \infty$ and $X_0 =0$
> Prove that a.s $\limsup X _n=-\liminf X _n =\infty$ or $\lim X _n$ exsits and finite.
>
> hint: you can prove ${Y _n}$ martingale then $\sup E[Y _n ^+]<\infty$ or $\inf E[ Y_n ^-]<\infty$

My solution did not use the hint so I want to make sure it is correct, and I would like to know how to prove the hint.

My Solution: 
Denote $M=E[\sup |X _{n+1}-X _n|]<\infty$, $T=\inf [n:X _n <-K]$ we notice $X _{n\wedge T}$ is a martingale and $X _{n\wedge T}>-M-K$
If ${T=\infty}$ then $\lim X _n $ exsits and is not $-\infty $

Now we take $K\rightarrow \infty$ and get ${T=\infty}$ if ${\liminf X _n >\infty }$. 
We do the same to the other side and get
If ${T'=\infty}$ then $\lim X _n$ exsits and is not $\infty $

And so we get the claim.

Comment: Is it specified that $X_n$ is a martingale? Regardless, your proof doesn't work because we only know that $\mathbb{E}[X_{n \wedge T}] > -M - K$, not $X_{n \wedge T} > -M - K.$